# How to install LinkedIn Insight Tag with NextJs

Tags: tags, next.js, linkedin-api

To install the Tag, linkedIn suggest to  add this snippet in the code.

They suggest:
"Paste the Insight Tag code below in your website’s global footer, right above the closing HTML  tag."

```
<script type="text/javascript">
_linkedin_partner_id = "93XXXX";
window._linkedin_data_partner_ids = window._linkedin_data_partner_ids || [];
window._linkedin_data_partner_ids.push(_linkedin_partner_id);
</script><script type="text/javascript">
(function(l) {
if (!l){window.lintrk = function(a,b){window.lintrk.q.push([a,b])};
window.lintrk.q=[]}
var s = document.getElementsByTagName("script")[0];
var b = document.createElement("script");
b.type = "text/javascript";b.async = true;
b.src = "https://snap.licdn.com/li.lms-analytics/insight.min.js";
s.parentNode.insertBefore(b, s);})(window.lintrk);
</script>
<noscript>
<img height="1" width="1" style="display:none;" alt="" src="https://px.ads.linkedin.com/collect/?pid=933188&fmt=gif" />
</noscript>
```

Where should I paste this code with nextJs? in `_document.tsx`?

Comment: Check Next.js examples for Facebook Pixel. It's pretty much the same stuff, just the code snippets are different.

Comment: No this is not true @Meglio , I have checked the examples given by NextJS. I do not see the solution there. Please elaborate more on the answer if you have one.

Answer (score 4):

I at first also thought `_document.tsx` is where this tag should go, because that is where I saw the `<body>`.

But, it turns out `_document.tsx` is good for [static things](https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/custom-document#caveats), and not necessarily for `<Script>` tags. Thankfully with [next/script](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next/script) there's a bit more freedom. With the `<Script>` tag, Next will use the `strategy` [prop](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next/script#strategy) to place the script in the correct place. `strategy="lazyOnload"` is probably the best for most social tags. And [`_app.tsx`](https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/custom-app) is the best place to put them.

I hope this helps, and good luck!

Answer (score 2):

You can use [nextjs-linkedin-insight-tag](https://www.npmjs.com/package/nextjs-linkedin-insight-tag):

- Install the module

```
yarn add nextjs-linkedin-insight-tag
```

- Get your [LinkedIn partner Id](https://www.linkedin.com/help/lms/answer/a417869/access-your-linkedin-partner-id)
- Add it as an environment variable:

```
# .env

NEXT_PUBLIC_LINKEDIN_PARTNER_ID=<partner id>
```

- Add the `LinkedInInsightTag` component to your `_app` page:

```js
// pages/_app.jsx or pages/_app.tsx
import { LinkedInInsightTag } from 'nextjs-linkedin-insight-tag'

const App = ({ Component, pageProps }) => {
  return (
    <>
      <LinkedInInsightTag />
      <Component {...pageProps} />
    </>
  );
};

export default App;
```

Full disclosure: I'm the author of this package.